# Java invalid entry counted

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how not to include invalid entries from being counted.
I need to enter 5 scores and want "score count" to 5, but the code I made only enters 4 "score counts", including the invalid entry.  I am not required to enter the invalid entry and have no idea on how to exclude the invalid entries from being counted as scores.

Here is the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TestScoreApp
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       // display operational messages
       System.out.println("Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.");
       System.out.println("To end the program enter 999.");
       System.out.println();  // print a blank line

       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String choice = "y";

       // get a series of test scores from the user
       while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
       {
       // initialize variables
       int scoreTotal = 0;
       int scoreCount = 0;
       int testScore = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter the number of test score to be entered: ");
    int numberOfTestScores = sc.nextInt();

           for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTestScores; i++)
           {
                // get the input from the user
                System.out.print("Enter score " + i + ": ");
                testScore = sc.nextInt();

                // accumulate score count and score total
                if (testScore <= 100)
                {
                     scoreCount = scoreCount + 1;
                     scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
                }
                else if (testScore != 999)
                      System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
                      sc.nextLine();

            // display the score count, score total, and average score
            }
            double averageScore = scoreTotal / scoreCount;
            String message = "\n" +
                 "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
               + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
               + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n";
            System.out.println(message);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter more test scores? (y/n)");
            choice= sc.next();
                 }
         }
 }
```

Here is an example of the file being run.

> Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100. 
>  To end the
>   program enter 999. 
>  
>  Enter the number of test score to be
>   entered: 
>  5 
>  
>  Enter score 1: 66 
>  Enter score 2: 85
>   
>  Enter score 3: 99 
>  Enter score 4: 79 
>  Enter score 5: 457
>   
>  Invalid entry, not counted
>
> Score count:   4 
>  Score total:   329 
>  Average score: 82.0
>
> Enter more test scores? (y/n)

Answer (score 2):

Simply decrement the loop iteration variable `i` if it is an invalid score, so you re-ask for that score. So change this:

```
else if (testScore != 999)
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
```

to this:

```
else if (testScore != 999) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
    i--;
}
```